# LazyInitializationException: Transaction across multiple EJBs

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, ejb

I am getting the following error from `EmployeeService`:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

Here are my code:

**GenericService**

```
@Stateless(mappedName = "GenericService")
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
public class GenericService {

    @PersistenceContext(name = "MyPersistenceUnit")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public <T> T find(Class<T> clazz, Long oid) {
        return entityManager.find(clazz, oid);
    }
}
```

**EmployeeService**

```
@Stateless(mappedName = "EmployeeService")
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
public class EmployeeService {

    @PersistenceContext(name = "MyPersistenceUnit")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @EJB(mappedName = "GenericService")
    private GenericService genericService;

    public void addEmployeeToDepartment(EmployeeBean employeeBean, Long departmentOid) {
        Department department = genericService.find(Department.class, departmentOid);
        // following line is raising the error org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
        Set<Employee> employeeList = department.getEmployeeList(); 
        Employee employee = convertToEmployee(employeeBean);
        employeeList.add(employee);
        entityManager.merge(department); 
    }
}
```

**Department**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DEPARTMENT")
public class Department implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2062922691486346594L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "OID", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long oid;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "department", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Employee.class)
    private Set<Employee> employeeList;

    public Long getOid() {
        return this.oid;
    }

    public void setOid(Long oid) {
        this.oid = oid;
    }

    public Set<Employee> getEmployeeList() {
        return this.employeeList;
    }

    public void setEmployeeList(Set<Employee> employeeList) {
        this.employeeList = employeeList;
    }
}
```

**Employee**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5328841678323494720L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "OID", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long oid;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "DEPARTMENT_OID", referencedColumnName = "OID", nullable = false,  updatable = false)    
    private Department department;

    public Long getOid() {
        return this.oid;
    }

    public void setOid(Long oid) {
        this.oid = oid;
    }

    public Department getDepartment() {
        return this.department;
    }

    public void setDepartment(Department department) {
        this.department = department;
    }
}
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">
    <persistence-unit name="MyPersistenceUnit">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>MyDataSource</jta-data-source>
        <jar-file>datamodel-${project.version}.jar</jar-file>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.validation.mode" value="NONE" />
            <property name="tomee.jpa.factory.lazy" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

- **TomEE**: 7.0.4
- **Hibernate**: 5.2.6

Comment: That's strange. Because IMHO your code is correct. Does it work when you find the department with the injected EntityManager instead of the GenericService?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli, yes that works. I have tested it. I am suspecting there is something wrong is happening when it is in multiple EJB. Perhaps the Hibernate Session or the Persistence Context is not getting shared.

Comment: The PersistenceContext is usually bound to the transaction. You have REQUIRED (btw. you can remove most of the annotations in your code because they are default). Have you the chance to test your code maybe in WildFly?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli, I cannot test my code in WildFly, as our official server is TomEE.